# `getElementsByTagName` for a `td` returns `undefined`

Tags: javascript, html, css, getelementsbytagname

Hello I'm very close to finish my demo site but somehow I can't get this simple piece to work.
Why the hell does the td return undefined when everything else is running fine?

```js
function find() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  //input = document.getElementById("search");
  //filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("table");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  console.log(tr, ("tr"));
  console.log(tr.length, ("trL"));
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    console.log(tr[i], ("trI"));
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    console.log(td, ("td")); //UNDEFINED?????
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="find()">Find</button>

<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" id="table" style="width: 50%;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Thema</th>
      <th>Typ</th>
      <th>Beschreibung</th>
      <th>Kontext</th>
      <th>SVG</th>
      <th>AI</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Gerätewelten</td>
      <td>Attribut</td>
      <td>230 Volt mit Gleichtrom Symbol oben</td>
      <td>Elektronik</td>
      <td><img src="1.svg"></td>
      <td>1.ai</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gerätewelten</td>
      <td>Attribut</td>
      <td>230 Volt mit Gleichtrom Symbol unten</td>
      <td>Elektronik</td>
      <td><img src="2.svg"></td>
      <td>2.ai</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gerätewelten</td>
      <td>Attribut</td>
      <td>230 Volt Standard</td>
      <td>Elektronik</td>
      <td><img src="3.svg"></td>
      <td>3.ai</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gerätewelten</td>
      <td>Attribut</td>
      <td>Analog Gleichstrom</td>
      <td>Elektronik</td>
      <td><img src="4.svg"></td>
      <td>4.ai</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gerätewelten</td>
      <td>Attribut</td>
      <td>Analog</td>
      <td>Elektronik</td>
      <td><img src="5.svg"></td>
      <td>5.ai</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gerätewelten</td>
      <td>Attribut</td>
      <td>Analog</td>
      <td>Elektronik</td>
      <td><img src="6.svg"></td>
      <td>6.ai</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gerätewelten</td>
      <td>Attribut</td>
      <td>Analog</td>
      <td>Elektronik</td>
      <td><img src="7.svg"></td>
      <td>7.ai</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gerätewelten</td>
      <td>Attribut</td>
      <td>Auge</td>
      <td>Misc</td>
      <td><img src="8.svg"></td>
      <td>8.ai</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gerätewelten</td>
      <td>Attribut</td>
      <td>Bad Smile</td>
      <td>Misc</td>
      <td><img src="9.svg"></td>
      <td>9.ai</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gerätewelten</td>
      <td>Attribut</td>
      <td>Bidirektional</td>
      <td>Misc</td>
      <td><img src="10.svg"></td>
      <td>10.ai</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gerätewelten</td>
      <td>Objekt</td>
      <td>Web-IO</td>
      <td>Wiesemann und Theis</td>
      <td><img src="11.svg"></td>
      <td>11.ai</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gerätewelten</td>
      <td>Objekt</td>
      <td>USB-Server</td>
      <td>Wiesemann und Theis</td>
      <td><img src="12.svg"></td>
      <td>12.ai</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gerätewelten</td>
      <td>Objekt</td>
      <td>COM-Server</td>
      <td>Wiesemann und Theis</td>
      <td><img src="13.svg"></td>
      <td>13.ai</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gerätewelten</td>
      <td>Objekt</td>
      <td>Microwall</td>
      <td>Wiesemann und Theis</td>
      <td><img src="14.svg"></td>
      <td>14.ai</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gerätewelten</td>
      <td>Objekt</td>
      <td>Web-Thermometer</td>
      <td>Elektronik</td>
      <td><img src="15.svg"></td>
      <td>15.ai</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gerätewelten</td>
      <td>Software</td>
      <td>Browser</td>
      <td>Misc</td>
      <td><img src="16.svg"></td>
      <td>16.ai</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gerätewelten</td>
      <td>Hardware</td>
      <td>Computer / User der auf eine Webseite zugreift</td>
      <td>Computer und Server</td>
      <td><img src="17.svg"></td>
      <td>17.ai</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gerätewelten</td>
      <td>Hardware</td>
      <td>Computer / User</td>
      <td>Computer und Server</td>
      <td><img src="18.svg"></td>
      <td>18.ai</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gerätewelten</td>
      <td>Hardware</td>
      <td>Server mit Attributionsicon für z.B PHP, SQL</td>
      <td>Computer und Server</td>
      <td><img src="19.svg"></td>
      <td>19.ai</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gerätewelten</td>
      <td>Hardware</td>
      <td>Datenbank</td>
      <td>Computer und Server</td>
      <td><img src="20.svg"></td>
      <td>20.ai</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please show your html as well.

Comment: Works for me with a simple table, the issue is probably with the html.

Comment: `getElementsByTagName()` always returns atleast an empty `HTMLCollection` and not `undefined`. Is that all the code?

Comment: i included the html table, the table is generated on site load from a JSON file which was very complicated to achieve so im rly close to get it done now

Comment: Notice that the first `tr` (the one inside `thead`) does not have any `td`.

Comment: The first row on your table doesn't contain any `td` elements. You should not get `undefined` though. Setting the `id` to `tbody` element instead of `table` might help ..?

Comment: Select the tbody before you seelct the rows. `var rows = document.querySelectorAll("#table tbody tr")`

Comment: I took the liberty of modifying your snippet to make it testable and, well, the problem is not what you're asking.

Comment: I cant edit the code now it says i should add more description: there is a [0] missing in td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];

Comment: @Jurijcorn I edited it for you. Is this right?

Comment: If it is correct, the problem is that you're trying to access the 0th element of an empty list (as there are no `td`s in the first `tr`. If you check the output now you'll see that there's a value for all the other `td`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate the `td` elements as well.

```js
function find() {
    var filter = document.getElementById("search").value.toUpperCase(),
        tr = document.getElementById("table").getElementsByTagName("tr"),
        td,
        i, j,
        txtValue;

    if (!filter) {                                                // no filter
        for (i = 1; i < tr.length; i++) tr[i].style.display = ""; // show all
        return;
    }
    
    for (i = 1; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
        tr[i].style.display = "none"; // move this here for a start value
        for (j = 0; j < td.length; j++) {
            txtValue = td[j].textContent || td[j].innerText;
            if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                tr[i].style.display = "";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search"><button onclick="find()">find</button>
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" id="table" style="width: 50%;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Thema</th>
      <th>Typ</th>
      <th>Beschreibung</th>
      <th>Kontext</th>
      <th>SVG</th>
      <th>AI</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Gerätewelten</td>
      <td>Attribut</td>
      <td>230 Volt mit Gleichtrom Symbol oben</td>
      <td>Elektronik</td>
      <td><img src="1.svg"></td>
      <td>1.ai</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gerätewelten</td>
      <td>Attribut</td>
      <td>230 Volt mit Gleichtrom Symbol unten</td>
      <td>Elektronik</td>
      <td><img src="2.svg"></td>
      <td>2.ai</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gerätewelten</td>
      <td>Attribut</td>
      <td>230 Volt Standard</td>
      <td>Elektronik</td>
      <td><img src="3.svg"></td>
      <td>3.ai</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gerätewelten</td>
      <td>Attribut</td>
      <td>Analog Gleichstrom</td>
      <td>Elektronik</td>
      <td><img src="4.svg"></td>
      <td>4.ai</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gerätewelten</td>
      <td>Attribut</td>
      <td>Analog</td>
      <td>Elektronik</td>
      <td><img src="5.svg"></td>
      <td>5.ai</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gerätewelten</td>
      <td>Attribut</td>
      <td>Analog</td>
      <td>Elektronik</td>
      <td><img src="6.svg"></td>
      <td>6.ai</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gerätewelten</td>
      <td>Attribut</td>
      <td>Analog</td>
      <td>Elektronik</td>
      <td><img src="7.svg"></td>
      <td>7.ai</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gerätewelten</td>
      <td>Attribut</td>
      <td>Auge</td>
      <td>Misc</td>
      <td><img src="8.svg"></td>
      <td>8.ai</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gerätewelten</td>
      <td>Attribut</td>
      <td>Bad Smile</td>
      <td>Misc</td>
      <td><img src="9.svg"></td>
      <td>9.ai</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gerätewelten</td>
      <td>Attribut</td>
      <td>Bidirektional</td>
      <td>Misc</td>
      <td><img src="10.svg"></td>
      <td>10.ai</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gerätewelten</td>
      <td>Objekt</td>
      <td>Web-IO</td>
      <td>Wiesemann und Theis</td>
      <td><img src="11.svg"></td>
      <td>11.ai</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gerätewelten</td>
      <td>Objekt</td>
      <td>USB-Server</td>
      <td>Wiesemann und Theis</td>
      <td><img src="12.svg"></td>
      <td>12.ai</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gerätewelten</td>
      <td>Objekt</td>
      <td>COM-Server</td>
      <td>Wiesemann und Theis</td>
      <td><img src="13.svg"></td>
      <td>13.ai</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gerätewelten</td>
      <td>Objekt</td>
      <td>Microwall</td>
      <td>Wiesemann und Theis</td>
      <td><img src="14.svg"></td>
      <td>14.ai</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gerätewelten</td>
      <td>Objekt</td>
      <td>Web-Thermometer</td>
      <td>Elektronik</td>
      <td><img src="15.svg"></td>
      <td>15.ai</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gerätewelten</td>
      <td>Software</td>
      <td>Browser</td>
      <td>Misc</td>
      <td><img src="16.svg"></td>
      <td>16.ai</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gerätewelten</td>
      <td>Hardware</td>
      <td>Computer / User der auf eine Webseite zugreift</td>
      <td>Computer und Server</td>
      <td><img src="17.svg"></td>
      <td>17.ai</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gerätewelten</td>
      <td>Hardware</td>
      <td>Computer / User</td>
      <td>Computer und Server</td>
      <td><img src="18.svg"></td>
      <td>18.ai</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gerätewelten</td>
      <td>Hardware</td>
      <td>Server mit Attributionsicon für z.B PHP, SQL</td>
      <td>Computer und Server</td>
      <td><img src="19.svg"></td>
      <td>19.ai</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gerätewelten</td>
      <td>Hardware</td>
      <td>Datenbank</td>
      <td>Computer und Server</td>
      <td><img src="20.svg"></td>
      <td>20.ai</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: this solution did work after a bit tweaking but that was because my code wasn't perfect to begin with.
i had to create an ID for tbody in addition because with your method really everything went missing.
Also I am stupid because I did kinda the same with for (j = 0; j < td.length; j++)  etc. when i wrote the script for creating the table in the first place *facepalm*

Answer (score 1):

After [this comment of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59754766/getelementsbytagname-for-a-td-returns-undefined#comment105656342_59754766) the problem seems to be that in the first iteration of the loop `tr` contains the `tr` inside the `thead`, at which point you do `td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];` which tries to get the 0th element of an empty list (since the first `tr` has 0 `td` elements), which returns `undefined`.

If you only have one table inside the page you can shorten your code a lot by getting the `tr`s inside the `tbody` directly by using `querySelectorAll` and iterating through them.

```js
function find() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  //input = document.getElementById("search");
  //filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  tr = document.querySelectorAll("table tbody tr");
  console.log(tr, ("tr"));
  console.log(tr.length, ("trL"));
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    console.log(tr[i], ("trI"));
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    console.log(td, ("td")); //UNDEFINED?????
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="find()">Find</button>

<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" id="table" style="width: 50%;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Thema</th>
      <th>Typ</th>
      <th>Beschreibung</th>
      <th>Kontext</th>
      <th>SVG</th>
      <th>AI</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Gerätewelten</td>
      <td>Attribut</td>
      <td>230 Volt mit Gleichtrom Symbol oben</td>
      <td>Elektronik</td>
      <td><img src="1.svg"></td>
      <td>1.ai</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gerätewelten</td>
      <td>Attribut</td>
      <td>230 Volt mit Gleichtrom Symbol unten</td>
      <td>Elektronik</td>
      <td><img src="2.svg"></td>
      <td>2.ai</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gerätewelten</td>
      <td>Attribut</td>
      <td>230 Volt Standard</td>
      <td>Elektronik</td>
      <td><img src="3.svg"></td>
      <td>3.ai</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gerätewelten</td>
      <td>Attribut</td>
      <td>Analog Gleichstrom</td>
      <td>Elektronik</td>
      <td><img src="4.svg"></td>
      <td>4.ai</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gerätewelten</td>
      <td>Attribut</td>
      <td>Analog</td>
      <td>Elektronik</td>
      <td><img src="5.svg"></td>
      <td>5.ai</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gerätewelten</td>
      <td>Attribut</td>
      <td>Analog</td>
      <td>Elektronik</td>
      <td><img src="6.svg"></td>
      <td>6.ai</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gerätewelten</td>
      <td>Attribut</td>
      <td>Analog</td>
      <td>Elektronik</td>
      <td><img src="7.svg"></td>
      <td>7.ai</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gerätewelten</td>
      <td>Attribut</td>
      <td>Auge</td>
      <td>Misc</td>
      <td><img src="8.svg"></td>
      <td>8.ai</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gerätewelten</td>
      <td>Attribut</td>
      <td>Bad Smile</td>
      <td>Misc</td>
      <td><img src="9.svg"></td>
      <td>9.ai</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gerätewelten</td>
      <td>Attribut</td>
      <td>Bidirektional</td>
      <td>Misc</td>
      <td><img src="10.svg"></td>
      <td>10.ai</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gerätewelten</td>
      <td>Objekt</td>
      <td>Web-IO</td>
      <td>Wiesemann und Theis</td>
      <td><img src="11.svg"></td>
      <td>11.ai</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gerätewelten</td>
      <td>Objekt</td>
      <td>USB-Server</td>
      <td>Wiesemann und Theis</td>
      <td><img src="12.svg"></td>
      <td>12.ai</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gerätewelten</td>
      <td>Objekt</td>
      <td>COM-Server</td>
      <td>Wiesemann und Theis</td>
      <td><img src="13.svg"></td>
      <td>13.ai</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gerätewelten</td>
      <td>Objekt</td>
      <td>Microwall</td>
      <td>Wiesemann und Theis</td>
      <td><img src="14.svg"></td>
      <td>14.ai</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gerätewelten</td>
      <td>Objekt</td>
      <td>Web-Thermometer</td>
      <td>Elektronik</td>
      <td><img src="15.svg"></td>
      <td>15.ai</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gerätewelten</td>
      <td>Software</td>
      <td>Browser</td>
      <td>Misc</td>
      <td><img src="16.svg"></td>
      <td>16.ai</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gerätewelten</td>
      <td>Hardware</td>
      <td>Computer / User der auf eine Webseite zugreift</td>
      <td>Computer und Server</td>
      <td><img src="17.svg"></td>
      <td>17.ai</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gerätewelten</td>
      <td>Hardware</td>
      <td>Computer / User</td>
      <td>Computer und Server</td>
      <td><img src="18.svg"></td>
      <td>18.ai</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gerätewelten</td>
      <td>Hardware</td>
      <td>Server mit Attributionsicon für z.B PHP, SQL</td>
      <td>Computer und Server</td>
      <td><img src="19.svg"></td>
      <td>19.ai</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gerätewelten</td>
      <td>Hardware</td>
      <td>Datenbank</td>
      <td>Computer und Server</td>
      <td><img src="20.svg"></td>
      <td>20.ai</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: i could only test the top solution at work so friday im gonna check this one out as well, gave you an upvote though thank you very much :)